# Setting "Note" field in PayPal Donation Form via PayPal Button

Tags: html, paypal

I'm trying to set the "write a note" field (which appears in the PayPal donation form) programmatically via a PayPal button.  The field can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7x9z.png).

According to the [current documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#individual-items-variables), it looks like I need to just assign a value to the `item_name` variable.  I have the following HTML, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxxxx.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hellooo!!!">
 <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
 <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</form>
```

Note: this code previous worked on the older version of the Donation form.  Could this be a breaking change?

Comment: NOTE:  this appears to be fixed now.  Setting "item_name" now fills in a "Purpose" field on the donation form.  I think this proves my point that they introduced a breaking change and have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version of the Website Payments Standard checkout flow the "note to seller" is no longer a supported feature.

A workaround for this would be to use an "option variable" to create a textbox in your checkout flow. An example of an option variable would be "os0" and "on0".

Here is an example on our website on how you would implement this: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside

Here is another link to HTML variable guide:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Please let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks, Brandon.  Are "option variables" applicable to a donation button?  I see documentation saying that it's not.

Comment: We have been using the option variables successfully until recently (say the last 6 months). We use the to allow the donor to specify a code for a book drive. However we are now finding they don't get transmitted reliably (ie. sometimes they show up on the transaction, sometimes not). We think it is because paypal is using a new streamlined donation form.